# How to find distance to each point inside rectangle?

Tags: math, geometry

For a given **Xp,Yp** and **angle** a inside a rectangle with (**width = Xm, height = Ym**) i need to find all distances **d_angle** (with angle between 0 and 359). I found a solution but it is too complicated. Maybe there is a simpler algorithm to find it in **python or c++**!

[image]

Comment: What algorithm did you find? And does it start by identifying which quadrant `angle` is in?

Comment: So... you want 360 distances to rectangle sides or something else? If yes - how are you going to use them?

Comment: @Beta my algo uses trainagles propriaties, but is very long.

Comment: @MBo I need to know the distance between point (Xp,Yp) and the rectangle for each angle (0-359). I will use that to determine for a certain point is inside the rectangle or not.

Comment: But checking if some point lies inside rectangle is very simple, in doesn't require knowing any distances.

Comment: @MBo How does that happen?

Comment: I added answer. Hope it is what you need.

Comment: Please explain your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check whether point `P` lies inside rectangle `R`:

```
if (P.X <= R.Right) and (P.X >= R.Left) and (P.Y <= R.Top) and (P.Y >= R.Bottom)
```

and note that math libraries of many programming languages contain function like `PtInRect`

Answer (score 0):

You can find the azimuths of the four corners from the given point Xp, Yp, let a, b, c, d. These define four angular sectors that "see" the four sides. (To handle angle wraparound, consider the sectors [a, b), [b, c), [c, d) and [d-2π, a)U[d, a+2π)).

Now the distance to the right vertical side X=Xm is (Xm - Xp)/cos Θ. There are similar formulas for the other sides.